# excel - count blank cells (Translating A to 1, D to 4.etc)

Tags: excel, vba

I want to supply a number (ie. 4 which represents the 4th column - D) and then have a msgbox return the number of non blanks in that column

For example below there are 5 blanks in column D:

```
col A     col B      col C     col D     col E
------   -------     ----     -------    ------
                               gh


                               2h



                               34
```

code so far:

```
Sub Tester()
CountBlanks 4
End Sub

Sub CountBlanks(ByVal colNum)
columnLetter = ??
columnCount = ??
MsgBox "Count of column: " & columnLetter & " is " & columnCount 
End Sub
```

Expected result:

```
"Count of column: D is 5"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends on what you actually want to count:

1. All blank cells in a column with respect to the entire table.
2. All blank cells up to the last used cell within the specific column itself.

Most people are trying to achieve the first option which is a little tricky. 
For counting blanks the specialcells function is the way to go. However as specialcells uses the sheets usedrange it can become unreliable as excel is known to keep track of the usedrange badly.  So first we must call the usedrange function to reset it.

```
Function CountBlanks(colNum As Long)    
    Dim sColumn As String
    Dim lBlanks As Long

    sColumn = Split(Columns(colNum).Address(ColumnAbsolute:=False), ":")(0)    

    ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    lBlanks = ActiveSheet.Columns(colNum).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count

    MsgBox "Count of column: " & sColumn & " is " & lBlanks
End Function
```

If you were after option 2 then it is just a case of getting the last cell in the column and counting with specialcells.

```
Function CountBlanks(colNum As Long)    
    Dim sColumn As String
    Dim lBlanks As Long

    sColumn = Split(Columns(colNum).Address(ColumnAbsolute:=False), ":")(0)    

    lBlanks = Range(Cells(1, colNum), Cells(Rows.Count, colNum).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count        

    MsgBox "Count of column: " & sColumn & " is " & lBlanks
End Function
```

**EDIT**

Jmax, the code is actually correct.  The call to reset the used range has to be on its own. On the next line when calling specialcells you don't need to specify usedrange.

Its hard to explain but try this: 
Comment out the ActiveSheet.UsedRange line.  With your test data add a value to a cell further down the page from the table and run the code.  It will return the count of blanks up to this newly added cell.  Now delete the entire row of the cell you added and re-run the code.  It will still return the same count because excel has not reset its inbuilt counter.  Now uncomment the line Activesheet.Usedrange, run the code and you will get the correct result.

Comment: nice and clear explanation :). Yet, i may have missed something but are you sure in your case 1 that you narrow your range to the `UsedRange`? Because you don't seem to use it in the `lBlanks` definition. Besides, i'd rather use `xlCellTypeBlanks` than `4` because i find it more readable.

Comment: +1 for the example e. @JMAx, I think In 1 Readify is using `ActiveSheet.UsedRange`to reset the used range prior to looking at xlBlanks (which will look at the used range not entire column). So it should work, albeit I prefer (2) for robustness. Both examples could probably use an error handler to cater for no blanks

Comment: The only problem with SpecialCells is that it will not count cells that contain spaces as empty; they technically contain data. This is a problem you hit from time to time with user-edited sheets. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks brett, your are right both examples will need error handling.   I'm not sure what you mean by you prefer (2), they are completely different procedures, they will return different results, its up to the OP which one is required for his scenario.  Jmax - thanks also, I changed to xlCellTypeBlanks you are right, I was being lazy.  See my edit too.

Comment: Joel, I don't understand your point, cells that contain spaces are not empty or blank.  I would certainly not want special cells or the worksheetfunction COUNTBLANK() to count them as empty.

Comment: @Readify, many users - and developers - would perceive a cell containing spaces to be the same as a blank cell. I'm just pointing out the less-than-obvious flaw that will upset some of the developers who come to this answer in the future and expect it to work on their column full of invisible spaces; hence "YMMV". (Nearly 15 years of Excel have conditioned me to TRIM every piece of text I rip from a spreadsheet. I wonder if it would have been better to have an auto-trim in Excel on cell values.)

Comment: Sorry I don't understand "YMMV".  Whilst I understand that perception, I would not consider any developers to actually expect it to work that way.  But I realise you are only pointing out a possible catch, thanks.  If spaces is a problem for anyone just run a find and replace.  Add a space to the find box tick match entire cell contents and your done.  This can be automated with vba as well and added to the top of this procedure.

Comment: @Readify: YMMV - "your mileage may vary" => for some people a problem, for others not. Here's a common scenario: Developer adopts COUNTBLANK, assumes it will fix problem, and it works for about 30 days until a user sticks a space in. Developer grumbles and adds in quick hack to fix space problem. The Find/Replace unfortunately will not work 100% as multiple spaces will not match. It's just something VBA devs have to aware of, that's all, including trailing spaces which causes text matching issues. (Incidentally, if you use @ + name in the comment, I get notified of your response.)

Comment: @Joel Goodwin. Thanks for the tip regarding @ + Name - that's very helpful.  If you have double spaces either do a additional find/replace for a double space or use regular expressions in a separate function and as a backup harness the worksheet change event to help prevent them in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `xlCellTypeBlanks` (thanks to brettdj for the column letter code (didn't want to search for it)

```
Sub CountBlanks(ByVal colNum)
Dim iRow As Long
Dim columnLetter As String
columnLetter = Split(Columns(colNum).Address(False, False), ":")(0)
iRow = Cells(Rows.Count, colNum).End(xlUp).Row
columnCount = Range(columnLetter & "1:" & columnLetter & iRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count
MsgBox "Count of column: " & columnLetter & " is " & columnCount
End Sub

Sub Tester()
CountBlanks 1
End Sub
```

Comment: No probs. Although pls note your current code builds in a hardcoded reference to column A (on your iRow definition), and when it is fully flexible it will give the same output as my existing shorter attempt.

Comment: Scratch the second portion of my comment as on balance of evidence it is blanks (title and example) versus non-blanks (body) that OP wants. First point re iRow definition holds. Cheers

Comment: @brettdj: thanks - that's corrected (i ran my local test on the A column :)) - it should work now (and counts the blank cells as you said)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the worksheet function COUNTA to so this, plus manipulate the column address with Split to get the aplhabetic columm letter

Note that any "" results will be counted

```
Function CountBlanks(colNum As Long)
CountBlanks = "Count of column: " & Split(Columns(colNum).Address(False, False), ":")(0) & " is " & Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(colNum))
End Function
```

Comment: The COUNTA function counts the number of cells in a range that are not empty.  I may be wrong but I believe the OP wants to count the blank cells.  Maybe you were looking for the COUNTBLANK function?

Comment: +1 Good point Reafidy. The OP did say "then have a msgbox return the number of non blanks in that column" and thats what I foccused on but the title says "blank". Blanks looking more likely from the sample output ...... in which case COUNTBLANK it is

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop and increment `columnCount` when the cell is not blank.

How do you know when you've reached the last row?